# Find $b$ and $c$ such that for all $x$ and $y$, $z = x^2 + bxy + cy^2$ and $\partial z/\partial x = \partial z/\partial y$

Tags: partial-derivative

Find $b$ and $c$ such that for all $x$ and $y$,

$$z = x^2 + bxy + cy^2\quad \text{and}\quad\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} =\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$$

Comment: Lemme guess: @ = $\;\partial\;$ ?

Comment: @DonAntonio Sir after you get (2−b)x=(2c−b)y, how can you get the b and c?

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=2x+by\\
\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=2cy+bx$$

So you have to solve **for all** $\;x,y\;$ :

$$2x+ by=bx+2cy\iff(2-b)x=(2c-b)y\;\;\ldots\ldots$$

Comment: Sir I'm still confused how to get b and c

Comment: Sir after you get (2−b)x=(2c−b)y, how can you get the b and c?

Comment: The secrete is in "for **all** $\;x,y\in\Bbb R\;$ " , so for example choose $\;y=0\;$ and check what happens...

Comment: Sir I got zero but i'm still confused

Comment: @iak, what happens in the last equality if $\;y=0\;,\;\;x\neq 0\;$ ?? Common, this is differential equations, you must know this!